# Find out the partition no/id

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way(A method) in Spark to find out the Parition ID/No

Take this example here

```
val input1 = sc.parallelize(List(8, 9, 10), 3)

val res = input1.reduce{ (x, y) => println("Inside partiton " + ???)

                               x + y)}
```

I would like to put some code in `???` to print the Partition ID / No

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, the `mapParitionsWithIndex` will give you an iterator & the partition index. (This isn't the same as reduce of course, but you could combine the result of that with `aggregate`).

Comment: Hi @Holden, mapPartitionsWithIndex() actually creates a new RDD. Where exactly is this method mapParitions() & mapParitionsWithIndex() useful. Any specific use case?

Comment: By using mapParitionsWithIndex you could output new elements which have their partition in it, then when you reduce you will know which partition you are handling the elements from. Was there something else you were looking to accomplish?

Comment: That exactly provides the answer to my question. Took sometime to understand. I have given the solution as a Separate answer. Good to learn from the expert :)

Answer (score 15):

You can also use

```
TaskContext.getPartitionId()
```

e.g., in lieu of the presently missing foreachPartitionWithIndex()

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5927#issuecomment-99697229

Answer (score 6):

Posting the answer here using `mapParitionsWithIndex` based on suggestion by @Holden.

I have created an RDD(`Input`) with 3 Partitions. The elements in `input` is tagged with the Partition Index(`index`) in the call to `mapPartitionsWithIndex`

```
scala> val input = sc.parallelize(11 to 17, 3)
input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[9] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> input.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (index, itr) => itr.toList.map(x => x + "#" + index).iterator }.collect()
res8: Array[String] = Array(11#0, 12#0, 13#1, 14#1, 15#2, 16#2, 17#2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this old question while looking for the `spark_partition_id` sql function for `DataFrame`.

```
val input = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(11 to 17, 3)
input.toDF.withColumn("id",spark_partition_id).rdd.collect

res7: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([11,0], [12,0], [13,1], [14,1], [15,2], [16,2], [17,2])
```